# How can I ensure that WPF UserControl elements are visible outside the bounds of the control?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, grid, clipping

I have a UserControl containing interactive elements within a grid.  The user can move and resize these elements, often causing them to fall outside the bounds of my control.  When elements do fall outside, I don't want them to clip.  I want them to be visible no matter what.  Unfortunately, setting ClipToBounds to FALSE did not solve the problem.

Even in the past during a similar situation, I had used ClipToBounds, and while it appeared to work at first, I noticed that out-of-bounds elements occasionally disappeared when dragged to certain locations.  There didn't seem to be a logical explanation as to why they disappeared except that perhaps the layout system was out-prioritizing ClipToBounds being set to false, only at certain locations.

It was very annoying and my work-around involved programmatically resizing my UserControl constantly to encase all inner elements, which seems to be a very bad approach.  Is there a cleaner way to ensure that my elements are always visible outside the bounds of my control (preferably without using ClipToBounds - is there a property I'm missing here)?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFIK Canvas do not clip...